# What is the best way to parse XML data that might contain empty nodes?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the parse XML service to parse some XML date. However sometimes there are child nodes that do not exist then I get an error if I try to `getText()` of undefined. So I started writing if statements to check every child node for undefined. Is there a better way?

```
  var document = XmlService.parse(rawData);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var entries = root.getChildren();
  for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var name = entries[i].getChild('name').getText();
    var webAddresses = contactData.getChild('web-addresses');
    // Checks to see if webAddresses actually exists
    if (webAddresses != undefined) {
      var webAddress = webAddresses.getChild('web-address');
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/content. You can use the various asXxx() methods to determine the type of each element.

Comment: Will that avoid the need for my if statements?  To clarify, the code above works, it just feels clunky to have all of these conditionals.